# Необходимо ли ставить точку в сокращениях типа "млн гл" (миллионов гектолитров)?

Tags: сокращения

По логике после "млн" и "л" точка не ставится, но если они вместе? Как-то глаз режет немного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего страшного, если даже вместе. Глаз режет с непривычки, поскольку в окружающей нас действительности подобные сокращения с точками настолько распространены, что встречаются даже в авторитетных источниках. Грамота.ру десятки раз повторяла, что написание таких сокращений с точками общепринято (особенно в деловой документации), хотя и считается ошибочным.

Посмотрите, для примера, ответ на [этот вопрос](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=222170):

> Ставится ли точка при сокрашении млн, млрд,: 100 млн.т или 100 млн т
>   Заранее спасибо
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Верно без
>   точек.